# How to stop timer when external program is closed [Python]

Tags: python, time, timer

I am trying to build a Timer which is counting the time how long I used Google Chrome:

```
import subprocess
import time

start = time.time()
subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\\chrome.exe'])
end = time.time()

print(end - start)
```

The output is just the time how long the execution is taking.
How can I create the argument: when Chrome is closed = end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can put "subprocess.Popen()" in a variable and use poll() function to check if the process is alive or not:

```
s = subprocess.Popen(['C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\\chrome.exe'])

check = s.poll()

if check == none:
   #subprocess is alive
else:
   #subprocess is terminated
```